# php code to show there is no result in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

If there is a select query in MySQLand if it has no result it displays nothing.
I need a PHP code which finds that there is no result in the select query.

```
$c="select * from stud where reg_no=$reg";
     $code=mysqli_query($con,$c);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code)) {
        $a=$row['name'];
echo $a;
}
```

here consider if there is no given reg no exist.

Comment: What did you find when you searched online or tried it yourself and why did it not work?  Please include this in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is only valid for `SELECT` query due the fact that `INSERT` queries only return TRUE\FALSE

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $c);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($num == 0) {
    echo "No results";
}
```

P.S: This is in plain MySQL i believe you can convert it into MySQLi alone.

Comment: @SetSailMedia, Question edited, code was neglected from the first post.

Answer (score 0):

use `empty` to detect that your array is empty as:

```
    if(empty($yourArray)) {
       //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to count the results in the result set.

```
$c="select * from stud where reg_no=$reg";
$code=mysqli_query($con,$c);
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $code ) > 0 ){ // Make sure something was returned
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code)) {
        $a=$row['name'];
        echo $a;
    }
}
```